# Get first numeric value from csv where all the first column shares same value in Python 2.7

Tags: python, loops, csv, match

I have a csv file like below. I would like Python to get the first numeric value where the cells in the first column share the same id. Then I want to store the ID and the value in another csv.

EDIT: The actual data is in excel but have been saved as csv. This is how the field would look like in excel. The CSV is comma separated with no header.

```
id          days
8215    \N
8215    \N
8215    700
8215    578
8215    1491
8215    1400
8215    486
18150   \N
18150   610
18150   730
18150   456
18150   548
18150   883
30610   \N
30610   792
30610   518

.
.
```

Desired results:

```
8215    700
18150   610
30610   792
.
.
```

This is what I have so far. I want it to only print the first numeric value after '\N'. Somehow, it will still print '\N' if there are two or more rows with '\N' in 12th-column. I would also like to save the ID with the value like the example above.

```
import csv

with open('sg_cand.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvReader:
        if row[11]  == '\N':
            print   csvReader.next()[11]
```

Comment: First, you say "csv" and don't specify a delimiter when you call `csv.reader`, but I don't see any commas.  The file seems tab-delimited, except for the header row, which (inconsistently) seems to have spaces.  Is that correct?

Comment: @DSM It should be comma separated and I don't have a header in this csv

Comment: Look at what you posted above in what you said the file looked like.  There are no commas, and you have a header row: `id          days`.  Is that what your real file looks like?

Comment: @DSM - Sorry for the confusion. I only used that as an example of how it would look like when I open it up in excel. I thought it might be easier to understand how the file looks like.

Comment: You used `row[11]` as the numeric column; I'm assuming that `row[0]` is the id here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - That's correct. row[0] is the id and row[11] is the actual data I want to get. It's part of the actual code but I had to truncate the example file as it would be too long for display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `set` to track what `id` values you've already recorded a value for:

```
import csv

with open('sg_cand.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    seen = set()
    for row in csvReader:
        if row[0] not in seen and row[11] != '\N':
            seen.add(row[0])
            print row[0], row[11]
```

This prints any `row[11]` value that is not equal to `\N` and whose id (assumed here to be in `row[0]`) hasn't been seen before.